# AutoHotKey open url on firefox in private window

Tags: firefox, autohotkey

I'm new to autoHotkey scripting how can I open a certain url on firefox in private window?

This script that will open url on firefox.

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

^f::
Run, C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\Firefox.exe "github.com"
```

but how can I make it open in a private window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press F1 to open this page in private window:

```
F1:: Run, firefox.exe -private-window "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61194402/autohotkey-open-url-on-firefox-in-private-window"
```

Answer (score 0):

In AutoHotkey v2 new private tabs in Firefox

```
; AutoHotkey v2
Run "firefox.exe " "-private-window www.google.com/"
WinWait("ahk_class MozillaWindowClass")
WinActivate
```